How do I sync threads that are in the same block but doing a different operation in cuda c/c++?
I am a 4th year university student who is working on a Parallel computing course project. I have made a very bad decision in selecting the right algorithm to show case the gpu performance compared with its sequential counterpart. The Bat optimization algorithm is what I chose and the parallelization is as follows:
Thread 0: responsible for calculating average and applying stopping criteria by updating flag.
All other threads: updating each property of each bat in a generation/iteration of bat population.
First look at the code:
__device__ void startAlgo(Bat *bats, int N, unsigned long long seed){
    __shared__ float global_best_fitness;
    __shared__ float average_best_position_of_batSwarm;
    __shared__ float global_best_position;
    curandState *state = new curandState;  // Should ideally be per-thread and persistent, not recreated in a loop

    // Initialize random states once per thread
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx < N) {
        curand_init(seed, idx, 0, state); 
    }

    if(threadIdx.x == 0){
            setGlobalandAverage(bats, N, global_best_fitness, global_best_position, average_best_position_of_batSwarm);        
       
        while(!stopFlag){
            printf("Average personal best position: %f\n",average_best_position_of_batSwarm);
            float prev_avg = average_best_position_of_batSwarm;
            CalculateFitnessAverage(bats, N, average_best_position_of_batSwarm);
            ApplyStoppingCriteria(prev_avg, average_best_position_of_batSwarm);
        //    syncThreads();  // Synchronize after potentially modifying stopFlag or other shared variables
        }
    } else {
        
        while(!stopFlag){  // Ensure this check is dynamic

            for(int i = threadIdx.x; i < N; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x){  // Distribute work more evenly
                performWork(&bats[i], global_best_position, state);
                        printf("id: %d, v: %f, p: %f, f: %f, l: %f, pr: %f, fit: %f, pbfit: %f, pbp: %f\n",i,bats[i].velocity,bats[i].position,bats[i].frequency,bats[i].loudness,bats[i].pulse_rate,bats[i].fitness,bats[i].personal_best_fitness,bats[i].personal_best_position);

            }
            __syncthreads();  // Sync all threads to recheck the stopping flag
        }
    }

    delete state;  // Clean up the state
}


This function is called after the initialization.
I have confirmed the fact that each thread indeed enters the function but what happens is that only thread 0 is doing its work in a loop and since there is no update in the Bat population, the program stops as a consequence. I have also confirmed that it has nothing to do with the fact that thread 0 starts first or anything like that. I even tried to add a spinwait mechanism to check whether the rest of the threads start doing their work at least once but no luck. I realize that there maybe a lot of rookie mistakes but since I am on Windows, I can't debug cuda programs.

On Pascal and earlier GPUs that code will deadlock, because on those older architectures threads in a warp execute in lockstep. Which GPU are you using? Debugging on Windows works with no problem if you are using MS Visual Studio (not VSCode) and install NSight for Visual Studio. Both are free: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/  and  https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition   Also, you cannot call __syncthreads() unless all threads are guaranteed to reach that line.

@Johan I am using NVIDIA Quadro K1000M(an old gpu), CUDA 9.2, VS 2015 so match the cuda version, but actually coding in vscode. Thank you for your input. Regarding what you said about the use of __syncthreads(), it makes sense why my code wouldn't work but I tried wrapping this in another function and called on both conditions so that thread 0 and all other threads will sync inside that function call but that didn't work either but I guess that's not how it works :). Either way, thank you.

NVIDIA Quadro K1000M is a Kepler GPU so you cannot synchronize threads in diverging branches (as pointed out by Johan). The PC register needs to be the same for all thread (ie. same instruction) for that and AFAIK all threads must be active. AFAIK, independent thread scheduling of Volta may help to make that possible (ie. newer GPUs).

Thank you for your contribution, it seems I have a lot to learn about what gpus can do. Should I close this question as I have solved the problem on my own? Or should I let others contribute and increase my knowledge?

You don't close the question, you accept the answer, you can always choose to accept another answer later, but only accept the answer if it did indeed solve your problem.

If you do not have a debugger, simply insert lots of print statements, that will allow you to see where your code arrives.
Structure the print statements as follows:
#define print(format, ...) do { printf("c T:%02i W:%02i B:%02i Line:%4i " format "", ThreadId(), WarpId(), blockIdx.x, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__); } while (0)

You might want to add __FILE__ in there as well, but usually you can derive that from context, so I keep it out.
NVidia GPUs really do not like thread divergence below the warp level. For optimal performance all threads in a warp need to execute the same code. Or at least a single thread in a warp needs to execute and the rest do nothing. This is much more efficient than have 2 (or more) threads in a warp do different things.
Also on Pascal and before threads in a warp execute in lockstep so if one thread executes an if and others execute an else, then all threads first visit the if path, with some threads standing idly by, then all threads (in a warp) execute the else path with the roles reversed.
If you do a loop where the threads within a warp diverge, you get very inefficient code. You can also incur deadlocks. On Volta and later you will not get deadlocks, but will still get the inefficiency, because the thread scheduler is only slightly changed from Pascal and will not issue different instructions to threads in the same warp on the same cycle.
Here's how I would rewrite your pseudo-code.
//init the RNG outside of the main loop
template <int blocksize> //make blocksize a compile time constant
__device__ void startAlgo(Bat *bats, int N, unsigned long long seed, curandState* state) {
    __shared__ float global_best_fitness;
    __shared__ float average_best_position_of_batSwarm;
    __shared__ float global_best_position;
    __shared__ volatile int stopFlag;
    stopFlag = 0;
    static_assert(blocksize > 32);
    assert(blocksize == blockDim.x);
    //assert(__isShared(state)); //perhaps store RNG in shared mem for speed?

    // Initialize random states once per thread
    const int idx = threadIdx.x; // + blockIdx.x * blocksize; //surely there is only one block?
    const int idx2 = idx - 32; //split this block in two
    const int blockDim2 = blocksize - 32;
    if (idx < N) {
        curand_init(seed, idx, 0, state); 
    }
    const int warpid = threadIdx.x / 32; //warp0 does the avg, other warps do work.
    if (warpid == 0) { //on K1000 only warps can execute different paths efficiently.
        setGlobalandAverage(bats, N, global_best_fitness, global_best_position, average_best_position_of_batSwarm);        
       
        while (!stopFlag) {
            printf("Average personal best position: %f\n",average_best_position_of_batSwarm);
            float prev_avg = average_best_position_of_batSwarm;
            CalculateFitnessAverage(bats, N, average_best_position_of_batSwarm);
            const bool done = ApplyStoppingCriteria(prev_avg, average_best_position_of_batSwarm);
            if (done) { atomicOr(&stopFlag, 1); } 
        } //while !done
    } else {
        assert(warpid > 0);
        while (!stopFlag){  // Ensure this check is dynamic

            for(int i = idx2; i < N; i += blockDim2) {  // Distribute work more evenly
                performWork(&bats[i], global_best_position, state, idx2); //to avoid having to recalc idx2
                        printf("id: %d, v: %f, p: %f, f: %f, l: %f, pr: %f, fit: %f, pbfit: %f, pbp: %f\n",i,bats[i].velocity,bats[i].position,bats[i].frequency,bats[i].loudness,bats[i].pulse_rate,bats[i].fitness,bats[i].personal_best_fitness,bats[i].personal_best_position);

            }
            
            //__syncthreads();  // Sync all threads to recheck the stopping flag
        } //while !done
    } //if !warp0
    __syncthreads(); //now you can call synthreads, because all threads meet up here

    delete state;  // Clean up the state
}

By dividing up the work into different warp, deadlocks between threads in the same warp can no longer happen and efficiency is greatly improved.
By moving __syncthreads to a line where all threads meet up, the blockwide deadlock in your code is fixed.
Beware if (x) { __syncthreads(); }
According to the CUDA programming guide:

Although __syncthreads() has been consistently documented as synchronizing all threads in the thread block, Pascal and prior architectures could only enforce synchronization at the warp level. In certain cases, this allowed a barrier to succeed without being executed by every thread as long as at least some thread in every warp reached the barrier. Starting with Volta, the CUDA built-in __syncthreads() [...] [is] enforced per thread and thus will not succeed until reached by all non-exited threads in the block. Code exploiting the previous behavior will likely deadlock and must be modified to ensure that all non-exited threads reach the barrier.

Translation, if you execute the following code:
if (threadIdx.x == 0) { __syncthreads(); }
else { __syncthreads(); }  

On GPUs prior to Volta, then warp0 will execute __syncthreads() twice and all other warps will execute it once, leading to a deadlock.
This is a bug in the pre-Volta silicon.
This is fine and will never deadlock
if (threadIdx.x < 32) { __syncthreads(); } //all threads in warp0
else { __syncthreads(); } //all other warps.


Really clever and insightful answer. Didn't expect anyone to write this much code. Although I have already fixed the code (see my answer), I will try your version as well and see how efficient yours is.

So I have updated the code to this:
__device__ void startAlgo(Bat *bats, int N, unsigned long long seed){
__shared__ float global_best_fitness;
__shared__ float average_best_position_of_batSwarm;
__shared__ float global_best_position;
__shared__ volatile bool stopFlag;
curandState *state = new curandState;  // Should ideally be per-thread and persistent, not recreated in a loop

// Initialize random states once per thread
int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
if (idx < N) {
    curand_init(seed, idx, 0, state); 
}
setGlobalandAverage(bats, N, global_best_fitness, global_best_position, average_best_position_of_batSwarm);        

while(!stopFlag){
    int stride =  (blockDim.x-1) * gridDim.x;
    for(int i=threadIdx.x;i<N;i+=stride){
        if(threadIdx.x!=0) performWork(&bats[i],global_best_position,state);

        printf("this is thread: %d\t",threadIdx.x);
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if(threadIdx.x==0){
        float prev_avg = average_best_position_of_batSwarm;
        CalculateFitnessAverage(bats, N, average_best_position_of_batSwarm);
        ApplyStoppingCriteria(prev_avg, average_best_position_of_batSwarm,stopFlag);
    }
        printf("\n");

}

delete state;  // Clean up the state}

Now every thread will reach the __syncthread() line and thread 0 will not dominate the block and work as intented and the stride calculation is also correct, that is, no index is left for calculation.

Change the if threadIdx.x == 0 to if threadIdx.x < 32 and you'll get much better performance, same for threadIdx.x != 0 to threadIdx.x >= 32. Avoid thread divergence within the same warp at all costs.

This code has a bug, it skips bats[0], bats[stride], bats[stride*2], etc. Also you did not initialize stopFlag, although in DEBUG __shared__ vars are zero initialized.

Ok let me try your suggestion. And stopFLag is already initalized as device volatile bool stopFlag;, globally so no worries there. And thanks for pointing out the bug as well, don't know how I missed that.
